# Split text needs space to give me an empty item?

Tags: ruby, split

Do I really need space to get three elements after split? Or could someone explain why is that so? *(note: code in ruby, not sure how it is in different languages)*

```
test1="2011112512215| | "
test2="2011112512215||"

puts test1.split("|").length    # =3
puts test2.split("|").length    # =1
```

Comment: There is not method `spit` for `String`. Did you mean `split`? Also, there is no variable `text` defined in your code. Did you mean `test2`? And, why are the strings named inconsistently with the first one as `text` and the second one as `test`? Potentially an interesting question, but -1 for sloppyness.

Comment: First of all fix your question, you are using text and test and spit instead of split

Comment: I fixed it for Radek, it was clear what his question was even though he wrote a really bad testcase. No need for the super bashing of this young mans soul.

Comment: @refp Radek has fixed it before your fix. You just changed the name from text to test.

Comment: @sawa: I realized but... it it doesn't matter ... now :-)) Better if no fix was need in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) takes a second parameter where you can specify a limit for the number of splits that will occure.

Passing a negative value will make the function not remove trailing elements of length `0`.

```
puts "2011112512215||".split ("|", -1)        # = ["2011112512215","",""]
puts "2011112512215||".split ("|", -1).length # = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative number for the length argument so that trailing nils are not suppressed (as per split manual):

```
        text="2011112512215||"
        puts text.split("|", -1).length
```